# NSOpenPanel - title not displayed and window not closing

Tags: swift, macos, nsopenpanel

I am building a toolbar app with a menu containing one option that displays a NSOpenPanel in order to let the user select a folder.
It is working fine except that the title is not displayed on the NSOpenPanel and that I have to use a tricky method to close the window after the "OK" button has been hit.

Here is my code :

```
let dialogue = NSOpenPanel()
                dialogue.title                   = "Choisissez un répertoire"
                dialogue.canChooseFiles          = false
                dialogue.showsResizeIndicator    = true
                dialogue.showsHiddenFiles        = false
                dialogue.canChooseDirectories    = true
                dialogue.canCreateDirectories    = false
                dialogue.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                dialogue.allowedFileTypes        = [""]

    if (dialogue.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK) 
    {

                    let result = dialogue.url

                    dialogue.setIsMiniaturized(true)
                    dialogue.setIsVisible(false)
                    dialogue.close()

                    if (result != nil)
                    {
                      let path = result!.path

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      return
                    }
    }
```

I have not found a way to display the title although it is configured.
I have to use setIsMiniaturized(true) and setIsVisible(false) before closing the NSOpenPanel otherwise it is only closing at the end of the process.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Yes, it is the same post. I guess I have miss it during my search. I have tested it and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OSX 10.11 the title is not shown any more. You can misuse the `message` property if you really need to show some text:

```
let fileDialog = NSOpenPanel()
fileDialog.message = "Your message"
```

Comment: Thank U. Should I open another post for the second problem (closing the window)?